# Ошибка: "mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL ..."

Tags: php, mysql

Помогите, пишет вот такую ошибку

> `Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in Z:\home\php\www\save_user.php on line 156.`

Вот половина кода:

```
$password = md5($password);
$password = strrev($password);
$password = $password."b3p6f";

include ("bd.php");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE login='$login'",$db);
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if (!empty($myrow['id'])) {
    exit ("Извините, введённый вами логин уже зарегистрирован. Введите другой логин."); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет результата от базы.

```
mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE login='$login'",$db) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 1):

Не получается выполнить действие по отношению к таблице БД ! Ошибка вылетает на

```
 $myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

потому что подключение не удалось...
Надо проверить корректность подключения к БД, хост, пароль и пользователя, затем, если все указано верно, надо убедиться, что у пользователя достаточно прав для доступа к нужной таблице( это самая частая ошибка ) и, наконец, проверьте корректность имени таблицы "users".

Comment: Вот у меня всё правильно написано в phpmyadmin всё правильно написано логин пароль всё, но теперь пишет "База данных не выбрана".
Что делать?

Comment: нужно выбрать бд
mysql_select_db('имя_базы_данных');

Comment: это в кавычках?

Answer (score 1):

No database selected вот это пишет и я не знаю что мне делать,а подключаюсь я вот так
 <?php
    $db = mysql_connect ("localhost","сдесь логин","пароль");
    mysql_select_db ("mysql",$db);
    ?>

Answer (score 0):

Вы возвращаете 2 лишних массива! Это же ужас какой-то, для проверки уникальности есть другой метод

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
    echo 'Такой логин занят';
    }
```

и все!

```
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if (!empty($myrow['id'])) {
    exit ("Извините, введённый вами логин уже зарегистрирован. Введите другой логин."); 
}
```

можно удалить